# Python If Elseif Else working strange

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Guys I was trying very basic program in python using `id`, `elif` and `else` statements. I feel something is not right. Check out my code below.

```
YourChoice = input(str("Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): "))

YourChoiceLower = YourChoice.lower()

if YourChoiceLower == 'y' or 'yes':
    print("Yes Block Statement")
elif YourChoiceLower == 'n' or 'no':
    print("No Block Statement")
else:
    print("Wrong Choice")
```

Now when I run the above code, it just asks me with the Y/N question. When I  type `y` or `Yes` it just return the `If` block statement
But when I type `n` or `No` it just Still execute the `If` Block instead of `Elseif` or `Else` block

check out the below Lines of execution

`>>>` 
`Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): Y
Yes Block Statement`

`>>>`
`Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): YeS
Yes Block Statement`

`>>>`
`Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): N
Yes Block Statement`

`>>>`
`Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): nO
Yes Block Statement`

`>>>`
`Do you want to Continue?(Y/N): Somethingelse
Yes Block Statement`

`>>>`

Can some one explain me what's going on, I'm confused why its working strange
 Please guide me friends 
 Thanks in Advance :-)

**Note: I'm using Python 3.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `YourChoiceLower == 'y' or 'yes'` does not work as you think it does. It checks if `YourChoiceLower == 'y'`, or if `'yes'`. The last sub-expression, `'yes'`, makes no sense.

Instead the condition needs to check `YourChoiceLower` in *both* sub-expressions, like

```
if YourChoiceLower == 'y' or YourChoiceLower == 'yes':
    ...
```

---

You could easily have checked this yourself, in an interactive session:

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> a == 'a' or 'b'
True
```

The result is `True` because `a == 'a'` is true. But then:

```
>>> a = 'b'
>>> a == 'a' or 'b'
'b'
```

Here you no longer get a boolean result, instead we just get back the string `'b'`. This is because `a == 'a'` is false, so the right side of the `or` is evaluated, giving the result `'b'`.

Comment: Oops! I got it now, Thank you so much :-)